# Seperate items by an attribute type set in different arrays

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, rest

I am trying to seperate items by an attribute named 'ProductGroupName' that is returned in the restful API. I want to loop through and create a seperate array for each section with the items listed as that attribute inside each.

I can manipulate my SQL on the server side to change how results are given but it would cause problems; here is an example result:

```
{ 
"message": "Success",
  "data": [
    {
      "StockID": 69323,
      "TradeName": "NAN OPTIPRO HA 1 GLD 800G",
      "ProductGroupName": "BABY FOODS",
      "SOH": 24,
      "MinimumSOH": 0,
      "Retail": 3199,
      "AverageRetail": 0,
      "Cost": 2848,
      "RealCost": 2791,
      "Reorder": true,
      "Message": null,
      "ListCost": null,
      "Markup": 12,
      "PLU": "476358",
      "NoDiscount": true
    },
    {
      "StockID": 18057,
      "TradeName": "NAN PRO 2 GLD 800G",
      "ProductGroupName": "BABY FOODS",
      "SOH": 19,
      "MinimumSOH": 0,
      "Retail": 2050,
      "AverageRetail": 0,
      "Cost": 2301,
      "RealCost": 1918,
      "Reorder": false,
      "Message": null,
      "ListCost": null,
      "Markup": -10,
      "PLU": "436178",
      "NoDiscount": true
    },
    {
      "StockID": 74206,
      "TradeName": "OPTIFAST VLCD SHAKE BANANA 12X53G (NEW)",
      "ProductGroupName": "WEIGHT LOSS",
      "SOH": 6,
      "MinimumSOH": 0,
      "Retail": 4799,
      "AverageRetail": 0,
      "Cost": 3937,
      "RealCost": 3086,
      "Reorder": true,
      "Message": null,
      "ListCost": null,
      "Markup": 10,
      "PLU": "294454",
      "NoDiscount": true
    }],
}
```

This is the standard output of all results though, so changing the result would complicate how I have written my REST service.

What is the best way to group these items?
I was considering looping through them, and when a new 'ProductGroup' is found, a new Array is created and that item is inserted, but that doesn't seem very optimised and I would like to know if theres a better way to achieve this.

Comment: `that doesn't seem very optimised` Why not? You'll see array/object-related answers recommending that sort of thing here on SO all the time

Comment: Im not sure, I guess it makes sense but I dont want to build any bad habits so I thought It was worth asking people more experienced in it

Comment: It's a three-line `reduce` function. As long as the array isn't 10000 items long, shouldn't be anything to worry about

Comment: I will say, I didnt even consider the reduce function haha just some messy loop so im glad I asked :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest way to organize the result of the request in a way you described in your question is to apply Array.prototype.reduce to result's "data":

```
result.data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const name = item['ProductGroupName'];
  acc[name] = acc[name] || [];
  acc[name].push(item);
  return acc;
}, {});
```

With this approach you will get following object

```
{BABY FOODS: Array(2), WEIGHT LOSS: Array(1)}
```

Comment: I get 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined'

Comment: @Cacoon My `result.data` is your "data".

Comment: Oh I thought I had to referrence Array.*data* instead of just passing the data; sorry im an idiot, i had already trimmed the data. Works perfectly, thank you so much!!